# C++ Do loop keeps doubling value when printing

Tags: c++, loops, getch

I have a problem with do while loop which is escaped when user hit some key. I increase some value by 1 every time it loops. But when I'm printing this value (after every key press) the value is getting printed two times.

The code is as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    int x = 0;
    char asd;

    do {
        x++;
        asd = getch();
        cout << x << " ";
    } while(asd!=27);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I need to check if the key has been pressed, but I dont know how to fix this issue with double printing every time key has been pressed.

Some help?

Comment: BTW: you've used a 'magic number' anti-pattern. `#define CHAR_ESCAPE (char)27`

Comment: @Dariusz And it's C++, so it should be `const char CHAR_ESCAPE = 27;` or (C++11) `constexpr char CHAR_ESCAPE = 27;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `getch()` reads not only the character you do input, but also the new line feed.

You do actually write `some_character` and `\n` into the input stream. Both are characters and both are read.

You need to ignore rest of the stream, after the 1st character read.

Another thing it might be is that some keys generate two character codes ["0 or 0xE0, and the second call returns the actual key code"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx).

You can see what is really happening with something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int x = 0;
    char asd;
    do {
        x++;
        asd = getch();
        cout << "Character code read: " << int(asd) 
             << ", character count:" << x << "\n";
    } while(asd!=27);
}
```

This will print actual key codes of what is read, so you will see what is going on.

Comment: There is difference in `getch` and `getchar`. In case of `getch`, no need to press Enter then from where `\n` goes to input stream?

Comment: Ummm... `getch` is depcrecated, and `_getch` should be used in its place. Also `_getch` and `getchar` differ more, the latter is defined in standard and echoes the characters, the former is a non-standard extension and documentation says it doesn't echo. The MSDN docs do not say anything about blocking. If you say `getch` is non-blocking then I am wrong. But then maybe OP presses special keys, which are coded with two characters.

Comment: @haccks Also please note that `getchar()` won't block if there are characters waiting in stream, it blocks only if the stream is empty. I assumed `getch()` behaves the same. Is that wrong?

Comment: *getchar() won't block if there are characters waiting in stream*: Yes, true.  *ut then maybe OP presses special keys, which are coded with two characters.*: This could be a possible reason.

Comment: @haccks When I get back home I will fire up Visual Studio and check for it. It appears that `getch()` indeed does not wait for the end line feed, and the only option for double characters are special ones. But I cannot check it myself currently.